# How to find complex eigenvalues via NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I'm using NDEigenvalue to solve following uncoupled eigenvalue problem:

```
V[x_] := (1 - 2/x)*(3/x^2 - 6/x^3)
S = -(1 - 2/x)^2 u''[x] - (2/x - 4/x^2) u'[x] + V[x]*u[x];
U[x_] := (1 - 2/x)*(3/x^2 + 2/x^3)
T = -(1 - 2/x)^2 f''[x] - (2/x - 4/x^2) f'[x] + U[x]*f[x];
NDEigensystem[{T, S}, {u[x], f[x]}, {x, 10, 100}, 30]
```

I have asked it to show 30 eigenvalues, but all of them are real. Can I find complex ones via some simple commands?

Comment: how do you know there are complex eigenvalues? And since the two equations are not coupled, why not just use NDEigensystem on each equation on its own? That will make life simpler I would think.

Comment: Hi @Nasser I want to know whether or not those two operators have common complex eigenvalue.

Comment: Well, my question remains the same. How do you know that they should have complex eigenvalues? Is this something you already know before?  Mathematica gave real eigenvalues.  And I do not understand the part about "common". These are two separate ode's that are not coupled.

Comment: @Nasser OP uses `{T,S}` (not `{S,T}`) which I think means they solve $T[f] = \lambda u$ and $S[u] = \lambda f$ which is a coupled system. But it also took me a moment to see this, it would really be good for OP to point such things out. (And I do not know why they write "uncoupled".) Btw, if I take another system such as `NDEigensystem[{T,-S},...]` I do get complex eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is this formulation:

```
V[t_, x_] := (1 - 2/x)*(3/x^2 - 6/x^3)
S = -(1 - 2/x)^2 D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - (2/x - 4/x^2) D[ u[t, x], x] + 
   V[t, x]*u[t, x];
U[t_, x_] := (1 - 2/x)*(3/x^2 + 2/x^3)
T = -(1 - 2/x)^2 D[f[t, x], {x, 2}] - (2/x - 4/x^2) D[f[t, x], x] + 
   U[t, x]*f[t, x];
NDEigensystem[{D[f[t, x], t] == T, D[u[t, x], t] == S}, {u, f}, t, {x,
   10, 100}, 30]

(* {{0.000575357, 0.000596462,.... *)
```

Note how the time derivative is used to cross couple the equations. But this equation does not produce a complex valued result. You'd need to clarify a bit why you think this should produce a complex valued result. For more information on the time dependent formulation, please see the documentation of `NDEigensystem`.